# How to use "with" on a generic C# type

Tags: c#, generics, record, with-statement

In any version of C#, is it possible for a generic class to require one of its type parameters to support a `with`-expression?

There doesn't seem to be a solution here:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/with-expression

> In C# 9.0, a left-hand operand of a with expression must be of a record type. Beginning with C# 10, a left-hand operand of a with expression can also be of a structure type or an anonymous type.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters

I'm aware that I could use some other way to copy data. I could require the type parameter to implement ICloneable, or my own custom interface for cloning. Or I could use reflection to try and emulate the behavior of `with`. But it would be ideal if there were a slick way to just use `with` instead!

For example, I want to be able to write something like this:

```csharp
    public interface IHasTime {
        DateTime Now { get; set; }
    }

    public record MyData : IHasTime {
        public DateTime Now { get; set; }
        public required string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsAwesome { get; set; }
    }

    public class Updater<TData> where TData : IHasTime /*, with-able*/ {
        public TData MakeUpdatedCopy(TData input) {
            return input with { Now = DateTime.UtcNow };
        }
    }

    public class Test {
        public void CanUpdate() {
            var input = new MyData { Name = "Frank", IsAwesome = true };
            var updated = new Updater<MyData>().MakeUpdatedCopy(input);
            ReferenceEquals(input, updated);  // Should be false
        }
    }
```

In this snippet, the only compiler error is on the `input with` part, which shows error CS8858: "The receiver type 'TData' is not a valid record type and is not a struct type." (This is on net7.0, so C# 10.)

Comment: In theory, this is not a duplicate question, because there *could* be a "with-able" type constraint that is satisfied by records, structs, and anonymous types. In fact, it might appear in a later version of the language. Even if the design direction taken by the language is that we shouldn't care whether a type is a record, such a constraint remains relevant. So it's useful to separately ask and answer that not only does a record constraint not presently exist, this particular constraint doesn't presently exist either.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible at the moment, there is no generic constraint which limits generics to be records. [From the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record#generic-constraints):

> There's no generic constraint that requires a type to be a record. Records satisfy either the class or struct constraint. To make a constraint on a specific hierarchy of record types, put the constraint on the base record as you would a base class.

The only thing you can do - implement a base record and constrain the generic type to it:

```cs
public abstract record HasTime : IHasTime
{
    public DateTime Now { get; set; }
}

public class Updater<TData> where TData : HasTime {
    public TData MakeUpdatedCopy(TData input) {
        return input with { Now = DateTime.UtcNow };
    }
}
```

See also:

- [Proposal : Constraint binding immutable types allowed to use "with" expression](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/6560)
- [record generic constraint](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/4315)